# Recursively do something with all files in a given directory including subdirectory files

Tags: bash, recursion

Okay so what i am attempting to do is to change a certain word in a file with another word. So if run the program like `./prog.bash document1.txt document Document` it will look in document.txt and every time it sees the word `document` it will change it to `Document`.

I was successful in accomplishing this however if the user inputs a folder name i have to recursively go through all the files in folder and change them all including the ones in subdirectories. My current program looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
function File {
    filename=$1
    echo "File $filename:"
    cat $filename
    if [ -w $filename ];
    then
        echo  "Changed into:"
        sed -i 's/'$old'/'$new'/g' $filename
        cat $filename
    else
        echo "File not changed due to lack of write permissions"
    fi
}

function directory {
    name=$1
    for f in $name/*; do
        if [ -f $f ];
        then
            File $f
        elif [ -d $f ];
        then
            directory $d
        fi
    done
}
filename=$1
old=$2
new=$3
if [ ! -e $filename ];
then
    echo "This file or folder does not exist"
    exit
elif [ -f $filename ];
then
    File $filename
elif [ -d $filename ];
then
    directory $filename
fi
exit
```

My current folder/file tree looks like:

```
                  Folder
                    |
       -------------|-----------------------------------------
      |             Folder3                  |               |
      Folder2          |                    Document1       Document2
      |            Folder4
   Document3          |
                      |
         -------------|---------------------
         |                                  |
         Folder5      Document4           Document5
```

So when i call the program with `./prog.bash Folder document Document` it needs to look for changes in all 5 documents. But currently it only looks for changes in Document 1 and Document 2 and then segmentation faults. I understand why this program doesnt work but i cannot figure out how i can search through all the subdirectories. Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're making this script more complicated than it needs to be. If the user provides a directory, rather than recurse it yourself, just build a list starting from the directory, such as `files='find $1 -type f'`. You can then `for file in $files; do ... done`. Note that the single quotes surrounding my `find` command must be back-ticks, but SO won't show the backtick as it's a special character.

Comment: @mah I have not learned about the `find` command yet. Is there any way you could explain what the find command is doing here?

Comment: @mah That's not a good way to iterate over all the files. It doesn't handle files with whitespace or some other special characters in their names.

Comment: It's be beneficial for you to try it out, but essentially it will recurse the directory root starting at $1 and, in my example, print the names of all normal files it finds. Since I'm suggesting assigning the result there to the `files` variable (if you replace the ' with a back-tick / grave accent / whatever you call it), it becomes useful for a simple BASH `for` loop.

Comment: @chepner that's a valid point but it can be worked around if needed, with a more complicated find command. Possibly `find $1 -type f -exec echo \"{}\" \;`

Comment: The recursive call to `directory` should use `$f` as its argument, not `$d` (which is undefined). With no argument, `directory` iterates over the contents of `/`, which results in infinite recursion that leads to the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get familiar with the "find" command. It's standard Unix, for traversing an entire directory tree. Try `find .` and you'll start to get the idea. Next try `find . -name \*.txt`. Getting closer :-). Finally:

```
find . -name \*.txt -exec ./prog.bash {} document Document \;
```

Comment: Okay so I got the program to work from what i was doing thanks to @chepner who pointed out that i was using $d instead of $f as my call to my directory. Is the solution using find however a "better" solution?

Comment: In terms of "don't reinvent the wheel" and "find has been *much* better tested/verified over time", I would say yes. If you're doing it only as an exercise for personal learning and not for general use by others, that's a different standard.